# Windows shortcut to Outlook's To-Do-List

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I created a shortcut to Outlook in the startup folder so it will open Outlook to the Mail tab at boot. I wish to add an extra outlook shortcut that links to Outlook's To-Do-List tab. I don't know the property flag for the To-Do-List though.

How can I open Outlook to the To-Do-List tab instead of the Mail tab?

Comment: You can flag it to open in to-do if you go to file - options - advanced - start outlook in this folder - browse - to do list
You want to have a different shortcut depending on which icon you hit? I don't think that's possible, you can just click the to-do list on the bottom of the left navigation pane

Comment: this works - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:To-do%20list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.

Try:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:To-do%20list

Or on 64-bit Windows :

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:To-do%20list

Make sure you leave the space represented by "%20".

[image: shortcut properties]

You can replace the parameter `To-do%20list` with `Inbox` to open the mail folder.

Comment: I can't type anything into the Target field. I went into the Startup folder, copied the outlook shortcut and choose properties.

Comment: @Norfeldt: The idea is not to copy the Outlook shortcut but to create a new one.

Comment: +1: Just tested this with Outlook 2013 (Office15) and it worked. :)

Comment: I've tried this method on Office16, but when I click the shortcut it keeps opening it Tasks rather than To Do. Does it have to be modified for Office16?
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select outlook:To-do%20list